Fully Faithful Right Adjoints
Give an adjunction $F \dashv G$, with $F$ continuous and $G$ fully faithful, Does this imply that $F$ applied to the unit is an identity?
I know that since $G$ is fully faithful, the co-unit is an isomorphism.
We have $\epsilon \colon FG \to 1_D$ and $\eta \colon 1_C \to GF$, as the co-unit and unit respectively, then $F\eta_X = n_{FX}$ is an isomorphism? I think I am missing something here.

$F\eta_X = \epsilon_{FX}^{-1}$ by the triangle identities, and $\epsilon$ is a natural isomorphism, so $F\eta_X$ is invertible.

Am I right in my above comment?

An isomorphism, not an identity.

Yes, but when is $F\eta$ an identity?

That is not a meaningful question to ask: identities have the same domain and codomain, but $FX$ and $FGFX$ are a priori different; you would have to choose an isomorphism to identify them with, but this violates the principle of equivalence.

That makes sense.
